# Get all elements that match a class name

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to get all elements that match a given classname on [this webpage](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfzocEm6IEDKVzVGOlg8ijysWZyAvQur0NheJb_I_xozgKusA/viewform). I tried `driver.match_by_class_name` but weirdly enough only the first one show up.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Programs\chromedriver.exe")
location = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iLqEFRaHPYxpJKU05VXt3HUCQ2OQUAg8FfWlyFbvaXc/edit?usp=sharing"
location = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfzocEm6IEDKVzVGOlg8ijysWZyAvQur0NheJb_I_xozgKusA/viewform?usp=sf_link"

class_name = "freebirdFormviewerViewItemsItemItemTitle.exportItemTitle.freebirdCustomFont"

driver.get(location)

questions = driver.find_element_by_class_name(class_name)
print(questions.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

`find_element_by_class_name` returns a single element. To get all the elements you need to use `find_elements_by_class_name`, which would be returning the list.

Your code should be like:

```
driver.get(location)

all_questions = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(class_name)
for question in all_questions:
    print(question.text)
```